# Show that being Long a caplet & short floorlet (both with strike price K) is equivalent to a FRA where you pay the fixed rate K

Tags: libor, forward-rate

How do you show that being long a caplet and short a floorlet (both with strike K) is equivalent to a Forward Rate Agreement where you pay the fixed rate K?

Comment: is this not the call put parity?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is put-call parity:
long the caplet pays max(0; libor - K)
short the floorlet pays -max(0; K-libor)
add them up you always receive libor and pay K